# How to check if a shelf is open?

Tags: shelve

Lets say I have a shelf.

```
subject_name = shelve.open ("subject_file", "c")
```

and  in my program I would like to make sure that I have opened the shelf and it is ready for me to write new data in, to avoid an error.

```
if subject_name == open:
    definition = subject_name["term"]  
    print( definition)
else: 
    subject_name = shelve.open("subject_file". "c")  
    definition = subject_name["term"]  
    print( definition)
```

I am wondering is my if statement Namely [if subject_name == open:] would evaluate to either  true or false. If it wouldn't How would i rewrite it such that it would evaluate to either true or false.

Comment: What decision do you need to make based on that information? Do you need to know whether *this* program has the shelf open, or whether *any program at all* is currently using the shelf? Do you have a shelf object, or just a filename?

Comment: Also, please don't use huge text.

Comment: Sorry for being vague I am still learning the ropes to all of this. I have added more details and would really like an answer.

Comment: If you have a shelf object, unless you've explicitly closed it, it's open. When you *do* close it, it'll generally be obvious that it's closed, simply because of where you are in the program.

Comment: Lets say I have two shelves.

Comment: Same thing. It should be obvious simply from where you are in the program what shelves are open or closed. If your program structure does not make this obvious, you'll want to change that, or it'll be very difficult to avoid resource management bugs.

Comment: Thank you. That makes things much easier.

Comment: But maybe another program or a different instance of the program is wondering whether the shelf is open.